# How to get hidden columns from datagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using the commercial version of material-ui [DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/), called x-Grid. It allows users to hide/show columns through the column options menu or the Columns Panel on the toolbar.

**What I'm trying to do**: I want to get information on current state of columns (which ones are hidden or rearranged) so I can save it for future visits.

In the [x-Grid API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/x-grid/) I don't see a callback fired when a user hides a column.

Is there a way for me to get that information from the component?

Comment: This issue is mentioned https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1507.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **onColumnVisibilityChange** prop available on XGrid where you can manage the hidden columns.

For example -

```
const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState([]);

return ( 
  <XGrid
    columns={Columns}
    rows={Rows}
    onColumnVisibilityChange={(col) => setHiddenColumns([...hiddenColumns, col.field])}
  />
)
```

check more - [datagrid](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/)